# How to do parallization while needing to check all rows in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe which has million rows and almost 100 features. I need to firstly cast a feature of them into string, then drop almost 17 features. Then I need to add a column to the data frame, this column called pred. The methodology I add this column is to group the rows by their "Reta" feature if -1 found all the rows with this class will have the pred value of -1 else this will be 1; this can be done with this code:

```
 #getting the prediction 
    hs_p={}
    for i in range(len(classes)):
        class_name=classes[i]
        #this can be rewritten 3shan law l2aina -1  n-stop bdl ma n-check kolo
        check=df.loc[df['CLUSTER'] == class_name]['Reta'].values.tolist()
        if (-1 in check):
            hs_p[class_name]=-1
        else:
            hs_p[class_name]=1
        hs_p_col=[]
    print("prediction done")
    #Adding the prediction column to the df
    for i in hs_p:
        df.loc[df['CLUSTER'] == i, 'pred'] = hs_p[i]
```

The problem is the data is very huge and it took me a lot of time to run and still no result. I thought about doing parallelization using multiprocessing library in python. However, I do understand that multiprocessing divide the dataframe into chunks, so the first chunk will have some of the class rows and another chunk will have the rest of the class rows, so pred column will not be done accurately. Any ideas about how to do this?